# Vector component and component's magnitude notation

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, vectors, notation

For example, $\vec{A}_{x}$ can signify $-5\hat{\imath}$. That for me is clear. However, $A_x$ seems to be a signed variable (-5) in some cases and an unsigned one (5) in others. This has caused a great deal of confusion for me. Gravitaional force is usually written as $-F_g$, so $F_g$ is unsigned, but then I see stuff like $F_g \hat{\imath}$ with $\hat{\imath}$ pointing upward, which must mean that $F_g$ is containing the negative.

Personal experience tells me that it's better for $A_x$ to be unsigned so that I can put the negatives when I need to, especially when working with multiple vectors, as in $(A_x - B_x - C_x)\hat{\imath}= \vec{D_x}$. But using this rule makes denoting the scalar part of the vector cumbersome, having to write $\vec{A_x} \cdot \hat{\imath}$ for just -5.

What notation rule should I use? Is there no symbol specifically for the "scalar part" of the vector component? The only solution I see is using absolute value signs everywhere, which gets cumbersome quick and is very easy to forget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have a vector $\vec{A}=[-1,2,-3]$, I write the scalar components as $A_x = -1$, $A_y = 2$, and $A_z = -3$. I never work with unsigned values. Working with components this way allows for consistent writing of vector formulas. For example, the [dot product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product)
$$A \cdot B = A_xB_x + A_yB_y + A_zB_z$$
or the [cross product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product)
$$A \times B =
\begin{bmatrix}
A_yB_z - A_zB_y \\
A_zB_x - A_xB_z \\
A_xB_y - A_yB_x
\end{bmatrix}.$$
There's no need to think about the signs of the scalar components when writing these formulas. The formula is always the same; just plug in the signed values.

This is similar to non-vector formulas. The position of an object that starts at $x_0$ and moves at a constant velocity $v$ for time $t$ is $x = x_0 + vt$. Do I care if the velocity has a positive or negative value? No. If the velocity is -5 m/s, then plug that in. Using $x_0 = 4 m$ and $t = 2 s$, we get $x = (4) + (-5)(2) = -6$. The object was moving in the negative direction as indicated by the negative velocity, so the formula results in a more negative position (however that is defined: down, left, etc.).

Comment: In the block on a ramp type problems, for example, I will set a new axis that is parallel to the ramp and calculate forces relative to that new axis. I might calculate Fg sin theta, friction, etc. In these cases where the forces don't really "carry" a sign in them already, I'll have to assign them the signs myself. This is why I need a notation for a nonsigned scalar component.

Comment: @mikeeei I see. I remember doing problems that way. The problem with using unsigned values is that, even if you are careful to get the signs right in the formulas, the result of the calculation will sometimes come out negative. It will then take some thought to figure out what that negative sign means. If you work with the correct signed values, the sign of the result of the calculation will always have a clear meaning.

Answer (score 0):

A vector has a magnitude and a direction. The magnitude is always positive.  A vector cannot be negative.  After you have chosen a coordinate system, you can find the components of a vector parallel to the coordinate axes. The components may be positive or negative. A vector may be given as the negative of another vector, but that only indicates their relative direction.

Comment: I understand. But this doesn’t answer my question on notation.

Comment: $A_x$ indicates an x component. It is not a vector and does not need a (.i). If you know the value, you might write it as (-5i), where the (i) is the unit vector in the x direction. In any case you need to get clear on whether you are talking about a vector or a component of a vector. (If the thing is in the direction of a coordinate axis, treat it as a component.)

Answer (score 0):

Each component value of a vector *should always be a signed number* indicating how far along a particular direction that component is.

When you see $-5 \hat{\imath}$, it can be interpreted two ways

- $ (-5) \hat{\imath}$

  5 units in the opposite direction as $\hat{i}$.
- $ 5 (-\hat{\imath})$

  5 units in the direction $-\hat{i}$

But to avoid silliness such as $(-5)(-\hat{\imath})$, as a matter of conventions all signs move into the component value, and $\hat{i}$ stands on it own as a unit direction.

Some compactness in notation can be achieved when using a mathematical vector, such as $\vec{r} = \pmatrix{ 3 & -1 & 2}^\top$ as opposed to $ \vec{r} = 3 \hat{\imath} - \hat{\jmath} + 2 \hat{k}$.

As far as gravity, make sure you understand that if $9.81$ is the magnitude of gravity, then the vertical component is $-9.81$ when counting positive $\hat{\jmath}$ upwards and the gravity vector is $\vec{g} = -9.81 \hat{\jmath}$.